# How to include the command "wget" on my C source code?

Tags: c, web-crawler, wget

I need to run a program that crawls websites and I already have an algorithm and some parts of the code. Problem is, I do not know how to insert `wget` into my source code. Our student assistant hinted that some kind of keyword or function shall be used before the `wget`( `system`, I think or something but I'm not so sure).

Comment: What do you mean by "insert" into your source code?

Comment: this calls for sockets! don't use `system` where you can avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever , you want to run shell commands from your C program , you use `system("shell command")`.In your case

```
system("wget");
```

Note - wget is an executable , whose location is added to the path variable, so there is no need to specify the path explicitly.

-- Example --

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFFLEN 2500

int main()
{

char web_address[BUFFLEN] = "www.google.com"; 
system("wget 'web_address' "); 
return 0;

}
```

Comment: @Sakamoto , it is wget followed , by the name of the URL system("wget urlname");

Comment: @Sakamoto , i have edited my example , to store the url , in a string , and use the string in wget

Comment: thank you for that, now I feel like I had actually understood the concept. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Sakamoto , no need to say thanks , if you find any answer which has partially/fully solved your problem , then you accept the answer , by clicking the tick mark , next to it

Comment: oh, haha, sorry I'm new here. I just did :)

Answer (score 3):

when to **not** use `system`:

1.) when you want to distribute the program to different environment, where the program you call via system is not available

2.) in a security relevant environment, where you have to make sure that the program you call is really the program you want it to be

3.) when the thing you want to do can easily be accomplished in 10-20 lines of C code

4.) in performance-critical applications

so, you should use `system` virtually never.

instead, to accomplish the same thing, you could use libcurl, as David suggested (his answer seems to be gone...), or do some socket programming (it's C, after all).

In a real-world scenario, I'd probably just default to writing the crawler in a different language. web requests and complex string processing are not necessarily the strong sides of C, and most definitely not very convenient to use :)

Comment: @BarathBushan because system spawns a new process, invokes the shell, which in turn probably spawns a new process and the OS has to manage all the nasty interprocess communication.

Comment: As I can understand from the question, it is a homework in `C Language` course, so your conclusion regarding to the `more suitable language, like perl` is a bit off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [system()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/) command.

In your case (possibly):

```
system("/bin/wget");
```

But if you want really call `wget` with parameters, so you should use [execl()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execl).

```
execl("/bin/wget", "http://anyadress.com/file");
```

Comment: bash: /bin/wget: No such file or directory

Comment: @BarathBushan it depends on the where `wget` is placed.

Comment: One more excellent demonstration why not to use this approach and to go for sockets.

Answer (score 0):

The `system` command is used to execute a shell command. [man system](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/system/)